# Using If/CASE statement in Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table from which I need to sum the values when a certain condition is met.

This is the initial table that I am querying from:

```
  Worksheet   Label   LOB        Data
  -----------------------------------------
   Layers    AAL    EQ-AO-US    64726.02706
   Layers    AAL    EQ-CA       171683.6675
   Layers    AAL    EQ-Int-M    858.9752352
   Layers    AAL    EQ-NM       9225.104696
   Layers    AAL    EQ-PNW      12554.17653
   Layers    AAL    NWS-Int-M   63142.0387
   Layers    AAL    NWS-US      300230.9489
   P&L      AdjAAL  EQ-AO-US    32363.01353
   P&L      AdjAAL  EQ-CA       251180.82
   P&L      AdjAAL  EQ-NM       4612.552348
   P&L      AdjAAL  EQ-PNW      6277.088264
   P&L      AdjAAL  NWS-Int-M   31571.01935
   P&L      AdjAAL  NWS-US      132993.08
```

I need the sum the data of the listed LOB's in the query and bring up final sum. To do this first I need to check if a LOB is there AdjAAL, and if it was, then use that one. Otherwise, I need to use the AAL 'Modeled' value for that particular LOB

**MS SQL Query**

```
select FileID,      
        Sum(cast(Data as float)) as Modeled 
        from Premium_DATA 
        where Label in ('AdjAAL','AAL') and LOB in ('NWS-US',
        'NWS-Int-M',
        'EQ-CA',
        'EQ-NM',
        'EQ-PNW',
        'EQ-AO-US',
        'EQ-Int-M',
        'StormSurge-US')
        and FileID = 17719
        group by FileID
```

The above query adds up everything from the LOB list and gives THE INCORRECT value as 1081418.51206399. But I expect the final answer to be 459856.5487.  (I got this number by adding following numbers from the above table)

```
    AdjAAL        32363.01353
    AdjAAL        251180.82
    AdjAAL        4612.552348
    AdjAAL        6277.088264
    AdjAAL        31571.01935
    AdjAAL        132993.08
    AAL           858.9752352
```

Any idea on how to approach such cases of using If / case statement in where clause or even a better approach to retrieve the final correct answer.

Comment: so if an `LOB` has two `labels` use `AdjAAL` first?

Comment: what is your rdbms?

Comment: its an MS SQL query

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza : yeah you are right. I basically want to check the LOB's first in AdjAAL, then move to AAL

Comment: Your "initial table" and your query don't match up. Table has Worksheet and Modeled, and you query FileId and Data. Is Worksheet a FileId?

Comment: I think you'd need to self left join on LOB, left side is AdjAAL, right side where AAL, then select modeled value from left if right is null

Comment: @Zack. the table is just sample of data from a very large excel file. I am actually only looking selecting the label with an if conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number` to select only the label you want.

I use the **[DEMO](http://rextester.com/IQXA80349)** in postgres but is the same on MSSQL

```
SELECT * -- SUM("Modeled")
FROM ( SELECT *,
              row_number() over (partition by "LOB" ORDER BY "Label" DESC) as rn
       FROM Table1 t1
     ) as T
where t.rn =1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Juan.  I never used this method before hand and I tried now querying using row_number as in my question and  it gives me NULL value. I am not sure if I follow the wrong approach

Comment: move the `WHERE FileID = 17719`  inside `as T`. Or use `(partition by FileId, LOB `

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of SQL you're using, On SQL Server you can use the CASE structure inside an aggregate function, e.g.

```
select sum(case when DOCID > 100 then 1 else 0 end) as DATA from DOCUMENTS
```